# iText 5.5.0 with XDocReport 1.0.4

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xdocreport

Can I use iText version 5.5.0 jar with XDocReort 1.0.4?
Are they compatible?

All the sample projects provided at https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/downloads/list, seem to be using itext-2.1.7.jar. Is there any specific reason behind that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDocReport provides converters docx->pdf and odt->pdf based on **iText 2.1.7** which is **LGPL** license although **iText 5.5.0** provides a supported version under **AGPL** license.

**XDocReport is based on iText 2.1.7 for license reason**. Perhaps it will be easy to switch to iText 5.5.0 just by renaming package from converter sources but never tried that.

You can read more information about XDocReport lincense [here](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/WhichLicenseApplies)

Comment: The developers of XDocReport are using iText at their own risk. iText 2.1.7 is no longer endorsed by its authors: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq Professional developers should not introduce iText 2.1.7 in their code. For instance: if you're a start-up looking for funding, you risk failing due diligence if you're using iText 2.1.7.

Comment: Please note that the scope of XDocReport is (by far) wider than the docx/odt -> PDF conversion. As Angelo suggest, I think we'll need to investigate the opportunity to provide iText 5.5 based converter in the future.

Comment: Maybe it is time to start to adapt other PDF creators like Apache PDFBox or PDF Clown in xdocreport. I think xdocreport is a great tool, and I would like to see alternatives to iText in there.

Comment: @ minni I have tried to implement converter with PDFBox, but it doesn't provide the same feature DOM like than iText. See https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues/54

Comment: @Angelo: I had the same idea, but as I sadly had not too much time to look into PDFBox integration. But I have found a good solution using the docx4j as a PDF converter with your xdocreport. Upgrading to the latest maven packages for docx4j, fop and xmlgraphics, everything is working fine and quite a bit faster than with your current maven dependencies to docx4j. If you are interested, I can give you my pom.xml, so you can upgrade your dependencies..

Answer (score 3):

Since XDocReport 1.0.5, XDocReport provides a version of the converter with iText 5 [org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.itext5](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/commits/master/thirdparties-extension/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.itext5)

Comment: XDocReport converters based on iText doesn't change the iText license.